# Como resolver este "Erro na sintaxe"

Tags: portugol

Estou com a seguinte questão e não consigo pensar em uma solução:

> Faça um algoritmo que leia o tempo de duração de um evento em segundos e mostre-o expresso em horas, minutos e segundos.

Meu código:

```
algoritmo "Duração de Evento"
var
   segundos, sec, horas, minutos : real
inicio
      escreva("Quantos segundos o Evento dura?")
      leia(segundos)
      horas<-segundos/3600
      minutos<-(segundos%3600)/60
      sec<-(segundos%3600)%60
      escreva(horas,":",minutos,":",segundos)
fimalgoritmo
```

Sempre obtenho: Erro na sintaxe

Comment: Qual erro de sintaxe e onde? Qual IDE de Portugol está usando?

Comment: O erro de sintaxe, está ligado a gramática do código, isto posto, como mencionado no comentário acima, sem tornar explícita a IDE que está a utilizar, não há como responder. No entanto, toda IDE (salvo engano), possui uma documentação da forma correta da sintaxe,

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo debatida no meta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6499/132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código:

```
  algoritmo "Duração de Evento"
  var
  segundos, sec, horas, minutos : real
  inicio
  escreva("Quantos segundos o Evento dura?")
  leia(segundos)
  horas<-segundos/3600
  minutos<-(segundos%3600)/60
  sec<-(segundos%3600)%60
  escreva(horas,":",minutos,":",segundos)
  fimalgoritmo
```

Consegui perceber em seu código que as variáveis estão como real, logo, não será viável usar o operador % para fazer o resto da divisão. Usando as variáveis como inteiro você pode fazer assim:

```
  algoritmo "Duração_de_Evento"
  var
  segundos, sec, horas, minutos : inteiro
  inicio
  escreval("Quantos segundos o Evento dura?")
  leia(segundos)
  horas<-segundos\3600
  minutos<-(segundos%3600)\60
  sec<-(segundos%3600)%60
  escreval(horas,":",minutos,":",segundos)
  fimalgoritmo
```

***EXTRA***

Agora você pode estar se perguntando o porquê da necessidade da mudança do tipo de variável de `real` para `inteiro`?

Os operadores `\`(divisão) e `%`(resto) são utilizados para divisões entre valores inteiros, que devem sempre resultar em um quociente inteiro e um resto inteiro.

Answer (score 0):

O operador `mod` ou `%` requer uma variável do tipo inteiro. No seu caso, você define a variável "segundos" como real, portanto é necessário que você redefina-a como inteiro. O código ficaria assim:

```
algoritmo "Duração de Evento"
var
sec, horas, minutos : real
  segundos : inteiro
inicio
  escreva("Quantos segundos o Evento dura?")
  leia(segundos)
  horas<-segundos/3600
  minutos<-(segundos%3600)/60
  sec<-(segundos%3600)%60
  escreva(horas,":",minutos,":",segundos)
fimalgoritmo
```

Acredito que esse código não atenda corretamente a proposta da questão, porém o erro de sintaxe não ocorre mais.

@Edição: No caso, uma das soluções corretas para a sua questão seria:

```
algoritmo "Segundos em hora, minutos e segundos"
var
   TS, S, M, H: Inteiro // TS - Tempo em Segundos, S - Segundos, M - Minutos, H - Horas
inicio
      EscrevaL("Informe o tempo em segundos: ")
      Leia(TS)
      H <- TS div 3600
      M <- (TS - (H * 3600)) div 60
      S <- TS - (H * 3600) - (M * 60)
      EscrevaL("---------")
      EscrevaL(" Horário ")
      EscrevaL("---------")
      Escreva(H," :", M," :", S)
fimalgoritmo
```